# Why can't I create a jwt token with SHA256?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am implementing a JWT based authentication for the first time, and based my implementation on some resources I found online.
I was wondering, my secret for the jwt is defined as:

```
"JwtConfig": {
    "secret": "pma_secret_2019_2020",
    "durationInMinutes": 1440,
    "issuer": "localhost:5001"
 }
```

Now I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
var symmetricKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secret)
);
var signinCredentials =
    new SigningCredentials(symmetricKey, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256);

var expirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_durationInMinutes);

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    Expires = expirationDate,
    SigningCredentials = signinCredentials
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
```

The create Token throws the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.
Algorithm: 'System.String', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey'
 is not supported.
```

Can someone explain why I keep getting this error? 
Is it related to the size of the secret or its characters or something else?

The code works when the algorithm is changed to HmacSHA256. But I want to understand why it doesn't work with SHA256.

Comment: I'm doing pretty much the exact same thing in my JWT implementation, except I use HmacSha256 as my algorithm type:
    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
Could you try that and see if it works? If it doesn't could you share the rest of your file (mostly just the libraries you are using / using statements).

Comment: JWTs need to be signed in order to guarantee that they were not tampered with. Hashes only provide protection against accidental changes as anyone who wants to tamper an JWT could just do so and replace the original hash with a recalculated one and nobody would know the JWT was manipulated. HMACs are key-based hashes (the key being the secret the JWT Sender and recipient have agreed on and are a form of symmetric signatures: so if one wants to temper with JWT one would additionally need to know the key of the original HMAC to generate an HMAC which would be valid during verification.

Comment: @ckuri thanks for the explanation. If you wrote the comment as an answer, I would have accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA256 is just a hashing algorithm, it doesn't provide signature mechanism. That's why [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) is there in the right option.

Answer (score 4):

Change 
SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256
to
SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature

Comment: The change works, but I wanted to understand why it doesn't work with SHA256.